# Detect press away/outside in react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Is there a way in react native to detect that I did press somewhere away outside my component.

I am looking for something like this: https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/ but specifically for react native.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I was looking for something like this: https://github.com/dcangulo/react-native-outside-press

We basically wrapp our app with this:

```
<EventProvider style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <RestOfYourApp />
</EventProvider>
```

And component where we want to detect click outside:

```
<OutsidePressHandler
  onOutsidePress={() => {
    console.log('Pressed outside the box!');
  }}
>
  <View style={{ height: 200, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'black' }} />
</OutsidePressHandler>
```